# Delete values selected using checkbox

Tags: php

I want to delete values that has been selected using checkbox. I am using this script though its not giving any error but its not working

please help it out.

for checkbox

```
<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?=$row['s_id']?>">
```

for delete button

```
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
```

for query

```
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{

$count=array();
$count=$_POST['checkbox'];
for($i=0;$i<count($count);$i++){
        $del_id = $checkbox['$i'];
        $sql = "DELETE FROM t_s_list WHERE s_id='$del_id'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
$NEW="Selected records Deleted";
}
var_dump($_POST['checkbox']);
var_dump($count);
```

Comment: It is is not working because `isset($_POST['delete'])` is never true. `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: than also its not working...
if I use var_dump($_POST) checkbox array is getting values but not records are not deleting.

Comment: @Sankalp: omg :-S tell me that you're kidding.

Comment: Wats kidding about this....

var_dump($_POST); output is like this.
array(2) { ["checkbox"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "21" [1]=> string(2) "22" } ["delete"]=> string(6) "Delete" }

Comment: @Sankalp: `var_dump` outputs the contents of things, showing you what they are. It's a debugging tool. It won't affect your variables and it won't fix the problem. It's a way for you to _spot_ the problem.

Comment: You say "its _[sic]_ not giving any error but its not working", but you never actually check for MySQL errors. Why not?

Comment: No error using `mysql_error()`. Showing the same output that I have pasted before..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the name of your delete button. `$_POST['delete']` needs the name to be 'delete'.

Also please check `$del_id = $checkbox['$i'];` It should be `$del_id = $checkbox[$i]`;

And for security sake

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM t_s_list WHERE s_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($del_id)."'";
```

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal : Sir wat I have to say instead of phrase "not working" if the code is really not working. Please let me know.

Comment: May I mail you my php page. Please share your mailing address.

Comment: @Sankalp: try to avoid "not working" whenever you ask on SO (or communicate with other professionals), because it conveys almost no information. Instead, describe **precisely** what behaviour you observe and how that differs from what you expect. For example ("the for-loop is never entered", "var `x` is null", "the statement is executed, but the row still exists in the databse", ...)

Answer (score 0):

You write:

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Delete">
```

but

```
$_POST['delete']
```

Use `var_dump($_POST)` to see what the issue is here, if you don't see it.

Also, where is your SQL Injection protection?

Comment: not working..
`    array(2) { ["checkbox"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "21" [1]=> string(2) "22" } ["delete"]=> string(6) "Delete" } `

Comment: @Sankalp: What do you mean "not working"? I suggested a way to find out what `$_POST` contains, which you've obviously now gone and used. Its output shows me that the HTML you are running is **not** the same as the HTML in your question.

Comment: @Sankalp: Then why does the HTML you showed us contain a submit button named "Submit", but your `var_dump($_POST)` output indicates that its name is "delete"?

Comment: Sir I have edited that according to suggestions. Now please help to fix this problem.