# Deleting records selected by Checkbox

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete values selected using checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752105/delete-values-selected-using-checkbox)

I want to delete records that has been selected using Checkbox

Checkbox code

```
<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?=$row[s_id]?>" id="checkbox[]">
```

ON delete button

```
if($_POST['delete'])
{
$cnt=array();
//$cnt=array_count_values($_POST[checkbox]);
$cnt=count($_POST['checkbox']);
for($i=0; $i < $cnt; $i++)
{
        $del_id=$checkbox[$i];
        //$sql = "DELETE FROM t_s_list WHERE `s_id`='".mysql_real_escape_string($del_id)."'";
        $sql = "DELETE * FROM t_s_list WHERE `s_id`= '$del_id'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        mysql_error();
        $NEW="Selected records Deleted";
}
$NEW="Selected records not Deleted";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to add my own answer which is basically based on @Sanjay Mohnani's answer.

```
if($_POST['delete']) {
    //store the array of checkbox values
    $allCheckBoxId = $_POST['checkbox'];
    //escaping all of them for a MySQL query using array_map
    array_map ('mysql_real_escape_string', $allCheckBoxId);
    //implode will concatenate array values into a string divided by commas
    $ids = implode(",", $allCheckBoxId);
    //building query
    $sql = "DELETE FROM t_s_list WHERE `s_id` IN ($ids)";
    //running query
    mysql_query($sql);

    $NEW="Selected records Deleted";

}
```

Please remember, that whenever you use any value that came from the outside world ($_POST, $_GET, $_COOKIE, etc.) in a MySQL query, escape it beforehand. These values can be easily manipulated by malicious users. This type of attack is called SQL Injection. You can escape values using [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

If you want to escape all the values in an array, you can use [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), which applies a function to all elements of an array.

You should also be careful when you output something that came from the outside world. For example you should never do `echo $_GET['something'];`, escape it properly for output (something like `echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['something'])`).

**Never trust anything that comes from outside.**

One more thing: in an HTML document, an ID can only be used on one element. In your code, all the checkboxes will have the ID `checkbox[]` which is not a good practice.

Please do something like:

```
<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?=$row[s_id]?>" id="checkbox_<?=$row[s_id]?>">
```

which ensures that your elements have a different ID or don't use ID at all. When you post the form, only NAME will be posted, ID is for the client side only (can be used with CSS or Javascript for example).

Comment: @bazmegakapa : Thanks. I was new with this implode function.

Comment: @bazmegakapa: Hats off to you Sir..Thanks a ton. Please help me to write the same function in another file. That is I want to navigate to other page (where I am going to write this function) when delete button is pressed. Still have written in that page.

Comment: @Aditii If you want the form to be posted to another page, do `<form action="anotherpage.php" method="post">`.

Comment: @bazmegakapa. One more question. I am using 2 files one is managing_records.php (for listing all the records) & another one is action.php (for taking action). I want to actions to be written on action. One is for deleting selected records and another one is for publishing selected records. Using form method as "post" in managing records I have successfully fired query for deleting selected records. But I wanna implement for publishing button also at same time so user navigate to action page and update accordingly query. As this time also I have to pass an array of checked values.

Comment: @Aditii Please open a separate question for that, comments are not suited for explanations :).

Comment: Got answer for my question. Thanks....

Answer (score -1):

try:-

```
if($_POST['delete'])  
{  
if(count($_POST['checkbox']) > 0) {  
   foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox)  
   {  
        $del_id=$checkbox;  
        $sql = "DELETE * FROM t_s_list WHERE `s_id`= '$del_id'";  
        $result = mysql_query($sql);  
        mysql_error();  

   }  
   echo "Selected Rows deleted";  
} else {  
     $NEW="Nothing to Delete";  
}

}
```

Comment: Using this code I am getting msg as "Selected code Deleted" but actually records are not deleting. that means `foreach` loop is skipping.

Comment: You don't really want to run 10 queries if you have 10 checkboxes selected. Build up **1** query in the `foreach`, and run it afterwards.

Comment: @Aditii, Do u have any element of the form that has the name of delete. Can you try placing an echo inside the foreach loop and see if its skipping, also place a print_r($_POST['checkbox']) . To get a better idea, before the loop

Comment: Oh and this code is also vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code,

```
if($_POST['delete'])
{
    $allCheckBoxId = $_POST['checkbox'];
    $ids = implode(",", $allCheckBoxId);
    $sql = "DELETE from t_s_list WHERE `s_id` IN (".$ids.")";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $NEW="Selected records Deleted";

}
```

Comment: thanks Sir, Can u please explain this code as I am fresher with this.

Comment: PLEASE apply `mysql_real_escape_string` on all of the POST values. Your code will lead to a security hole (SQL Injection). @Aditii: PLEASE don't use this code on the Internet until it is fixed by Sanjay.

Comment: -1 syntax error with delete query `*` can not be used

Comment: @bazmegakapa: please specify the code.

@ Sanjay and @bazmegakapa: I want to write this delete function in another file, can u please explain wat value is need to be send. how a code will be modified.

Comment: @Aditii All you need to do is `include 'anotherfile.php';`. Please read the [PHP Manual about include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). If you have further problems, please open a new question.