# Code for a checkbox that will enable me to choose which to delete in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, wamp, web-development-server

i have this code that will display the entries in my database.

```
<html>
<head>
<center>

<form action="delete.php">

<a href='display.php'><input type='submit' value='Delete Records'></a></th></tr><br><br><br></form>

<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

mysql_select_db("bfp6");

$result=mysql_query("Select*From station");

$display="<table border=\"1\"><tr>

<th><font color='yellow'>ID&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>

<th><font color='yellow'>Station&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>

<th><font color='yellow'>Email&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>

<th><font color='yellow'>Password&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><td></tr>";

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$id=$row['id'];

$stations=$row['stations'];

$email=$row['email'];

$password=$row['password'];

$z="<tr><td>".$id."</td><td>".$stations."</td><td>".$email."</td><td>".$password."</td><tr>";

$display=$display.$z;}

$display=$display."</table>";

echo $display;

?><html><body bgcolor="eb3a3a"></body></html>
```

and here is my code for deleting records (which in single click will delete all records except for the one with id = 234)

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

header("location:display.php");

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

mysql_select_db("bfp6",$con);

$result=mysql_query("DELETE FROM station WHERE id<>234");

$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

so guys, how would i add a code for a checkbox that whenever i click, let's say a button named "mark items to delete", it will appear and when i check those and click the delete button, only those checked will be deleted..please a little help here guys. i'm not so good at this :(

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: you might be able to use the answer over here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754328/deleting-records-selected-by-checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your header is redirecting before the database can connect...