# Deleting Checked box data in Mysql Table from form

Tags: php, html

I am working on an inventory program and I need help on the following:
I have a table that works through selecting data from my Database and showing this in a table.
I now need to make it possible for a user to be able to delete bad/faulty records from the form  ( Ofcourse u don't want to everytime have to go in the database itself to remove a record, would be stupid)

My code:

```
<div id="artikel-container">    
   <table class="table 1">
      <thead>
         <title>Inventory Grid.html</title>
         <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
         <style type = "text/css">
             table, td, th {
                 border: 1px solid black;
             } 
         </style>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
          <?php
             $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "admin", "inventarisdb");
             // Check connection
             if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
                 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
             }

             $result = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT * FROM BCD" );

             echo "<table border='0'>
                      <tr>
                         <th>Categorie</th>
                         <th>SerieNummer</th>
                         <th>MacAdress</th>
                         <th>ProductCode</th>
                         <th>Prijs</th>
                         <th>RekNummer</th>
                         <th>PaletNummer</th>
                         <th>Hoeveelheid</th>
                         <th>Aantekeningen/th>
                      </tr>";

               while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
                   echo "<tr>";
                       echo "<td>" . $row['Categorie'] . "</td>";
                       echo "<td>" . $row['SerieNummer'] . "</td>";
                       echo "<td>" . $row['MacAdress'] . "</td>";
                       echo "<td>" . $row['ProductCode'] . "</td>";
                       echo "<td>" . $row['Prijs'] . "</td>";
                       echo "<td>" . $row['RekNummer'] . "</td>";
                       echo "<td>" . $row['PaletNummer'] . "</td>";
                       echo "<td>" . $row['Hoeveelheid'] . "</td>";
                       echo "<td>" . $row['Aantekeningen'] . "</td>";
                   echo "</tr>";
               }
          echo "</table>";
      mysqli_close($con);
    ?>

    </article>
</fieldset>

</tbody>
```

This code works perfectly!

What i want to achieve is to select Records from this table with a checkbos and delete them by clicking on a delete button in the bottom of the page programmed like this:

```
<Input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Verwijderen" />
```

Or at least with this principle!

(This is the second ever application I wrote, 1st was a webpage, and I have no idea how to research this. I keep finding questions and posts that are just not what i need :S Hope U can help me )

Comment: You can post the ids to a new php server side script to delete by AJAX. The simply way is to use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Please go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752105/delete-values-selected-using-checkbox Additionally you will need a checkbox for all the records and an additional page to process the deletion. try googling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use jQuery ajax so you will be able to delete entry one by one without page reload.

At first include jQuery library in HTML HEADER and the Javascript script file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".delete").click(function(event) {
        var entryid = $(this).closest('tr').find('.entryid').val();
        alert('This entry will be deleted: ' + entryid); // this will alert you the value what you get. After finisgin to get correct value you can delete this
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "delete.php",
            data: "id=" + entryid
        });
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

in MySQL database must be uniqe ID for every entry named 'id'

Grid.html:

```
 echo "<td>" . $row['Aantekeningen'] . "</td>";
 echo '<td><input type="hidden" class="entryid" name="id" value='.$row['id'].' /><a href="#" class="delete">delete</a></td>';
```

delete.php:

```
// connect to database
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql="DELETE FROM BCD WHERE id='$id'";
```

Comment: Dear Sonali, thank you for ur answer but the Link u posted for me isn't very helpfull for the issue discussed in there doesn't get solved.

Comment: Dear Gatis,

I have applied all ur suggestions and this is one awesome looking solution! 
I simplyhave the option to delete right away on the same page!
Only problem i have is that when I click on delete behind the record, nothing is happening :S 
What did i do wrong? Or did u maybe forget something?
I litteraly copy pasted ur suggestions and added a conmnection to database for the delete.php but nothing happens :(

Comment: Dear Gatis, I dont know javascript and im not rly getting smarter in W3schools: should I change entryid with the mysql table name? or all the fields in that table? please enlighten me I'm new to this!

Comment: Sorry, I tested it myself and found 3 bugs on script.js
Try it now.

Comment: BCD table structure must look like:

id(uniqe, auto_increment, int), Categorie, SerieNummer, ...
example of row: 24, Transport, 00133445, ...

Comment: Dear Gatis, unfortunately still nothing is happening still.
Yet i see the structure of how this code is going to work and it rly looks awesome and I want it to work! :)
I just don't know javascript so i wonder if there is some code I can add somewhere to display/echo where what goes wrong?
I used this for delete.php:
 <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","inventarisdb");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
This should work would u agree?
What else can be going wrong :) ?
thnx in advanced for all

Comment: I added one more correction. Changed in script.js from POST to GET because in delete.php we have GET.

Entire <TR> is hiding and alert displayed after pressing DELETE button?

Comment: Dear Gatis,
After a busy week @ the office I am finally back to my app and a question has arised. The script is partially working becuz the action is executed and the data gets removed from my table in my form but the data does not get deleted from my database. Did u maybe forget something? Additionally this is only working in my test form script but not on my app's script itself, Is it possible that there is a CSS issue/influence keeping it from working?

Comment: If it works only at frontend, try to work with delete.php file and for testing run url: delete.php?id=2324 where '2324' is item id who needs to delete.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to wrap the table into a form

```
<div id="artikel-container">
<form name="form1" method="post" action="...">
<table class="table 1">
...
echo "</table></form>";
mysqli_close($con);
```

Next you need the checkboxs on the form $row['ID'] is the primary key of the table

```
  echo "<td>" . $row['Aantekeningen'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='del[]' value='".$row['ID'] . "></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
```

In the php file called in the form's action attribute:

```
<?php
if( isset( $_POST['del'] ) {
  $del = $_POST['del'];
  for(x=0; x<count(del); x++ ) {
     $sql = 'DELETE FROM BCD WHERE ID='.$del[$x];
     //---execuste the query
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for all your quick replies , this website is amazing!
Due to me being a beginner still with programming it will take me some time to comprehend and apply and test ur suggestions!

I will let u know what the results are!
Cheers

Comment: Dear Jeff,

After applying ur suggestions, Iget that I am not seeing all the data from Mysql's table in the app's table. Neither am i seeing the submit/delete button. Have i done something wrong or did u forget something by chance?

Comment: Thank you Jeff this tutorial indeed looks very handy and helpfull! thank you for ur attention! I will try it out!
cheers